# Expo Client TypeError: Network request failed

Tags: javascript, react-native, fetch, expo

I am running my react native code on expo client. When I try to fetch from *google.com*, for instance, I get

> "TypeError: Network request failed"

**error**.

I have internet on my device.
This error message does not make sense in detail. How can I understand the real problem beneath.

```
  static test(provider, token, success, error) {
    console.log(1); // TODO: remove
    fetch("https://wwww.google.com", {
      method: "GET",
    })
      .then(response => {
        console.log(2); // TODO: remove
        if (response.ok) {
          success(response);
        } else {
          error(response);
        }
      }).catch(e => {
        console.log("RestService Error: " + e);
      });
  }
```

**Update:**
Snack added.

https://snack.expo.io/@dijkstras/fetch-issue

Comment: Possible duplicated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56867456/network-request-failed-in-react-native-expo-client

Comment: I am trying to reach 'google.com' rather than a local area server. How could be the duplicate of the issue you mention, @Oleg ?

Comment: Can you post snack example and test it? I want to eliminate the connection problem device with pc and network

Comment: Added the snack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You added 4 'wwww' in url address.
fixed snack:
https://snack.expo.io/@djalik/fetch-issue

Comment: Omg -_- Why don't I get a better error message? I have assumed that it is something related with permission.