# React native - fetch data from external api getting Network request failed

Tags: react-native, axios, fetch

trying to fetch data form  other domain (ex. https://reactnative.dev/movies.json) form local react native application I am getting "Network request failed" error.

Can somebody please help for this issue.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cROjF.png)

Comment: Show full `Login.js`. Add it to Question

Comment: please add some code u use

Comment: I think this is will resolve with below link answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56867456/network-request-failed-in-react-native-expo-client#answer-56870086